# Code Externalization issues in knitr

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio

I have following code written in an r script "code.R":

```
## @knitr Q1

x <- 1:10
x

## @knitr Q2
mean(x)
```

In r studio 0.98.1028, in a Rmd file "bhi.rmd", I used following code:

````
---
output:
  html_document:
    toc: yes
---

```{r}
library(knitr)
read_chunk("code.R")
```


```{r Q1}
```

```{r Q2}
```
````

After `knit HTML`, the output was (as expected):

```
x <- 1:10
x
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
mean(x)
## [1] 5.5
```

But if I drop the chunk `Q1`, I get wrong output of chunk `Q2`:

```
mean(x)
## [1] 8.667
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: `knit` seems to run with the environment set to whatever you call `knit` from, which likely is your workspace, which likely contains a variable `x` with a mean of 8.667.  Also, it might lazily evaluate code, so if you don't include it in the document, it might not evaluate the relevant section from the source.

Comment: Does that mean if I have a R script file with 15 chunks of code and I want to use only last 3 in a Rmd file, I have to include the first 12 chunks with `eval=FALSE` and last 3 in default setting? If that is the case, then it is very cumbersome.

Comment: I did have a `x` object in global environment but even after clearing that, I am still getting 8.667 when I skip `Q1` chunk

Comment: Unfortunately I was just taking a stab in the dark.  I'm not very familiar with `knitr`.  You should still try to look at the `x` variable by adding it to Q2 to print to see if it gives you any hints.

Comment: what do you mean by dropping/skipping q1? If I set eval=False for that chunk, or if I delete that part in the code.r, I get errors, and it doesn't compile. And there are other ways to run only 3 of 15 chunks, but knitr cannot read your mind, so if you want to do something very specific like not run the first 12 chunks and then run the final 3, then yes you're probably going to have to explicitly tell knitr to do that. That's pretty much how all programming works

Comment: @rawr By "dropping Q1" I mean that if I don't want to include the chunk Q1 in the Rmd file (while it exists in the code.R), what should I do? Is it absolutely necessary to include the chunk in Rmd file with or without `eval=FALSE` or can I als include the select few chunks (in this case Q2 only)? If I can do the latter than why the example in my question is not working?

Comment: But you have to include chunk 1 because chunk2 depends on it. A knitr document is completely separate from your workspace meaning that regardless of what you have there, nothing will be in the knitr docs unless you provide them in a chunk *and* evaluate them. There are a few different ways to include and evaluate chunks, it depends on what you need. If you have a bunch of chunk and only want to evaluate three, you could set the global `eval = FALSE` and only set eval = true for the three you want, again, provided that you dont need the results of the first 12 chunks

Comment: To avoid confusion, please post a complete and reproducible example. Your current example is not reproducible. If I remove chunk 1, I will get an error `'x' not found`. My best guess is that you have an existing object `x` in your workspace: it is either from a certain previous chunk, or the `.RData` image that you saved the last time you quit R. To verify the latter, restart R, and type `x` (or `ls()`).